# Send Request To Apache Tomcat (localhost:8080) using GruntJs

Tags: node.js, apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, gruntjs

Hi I have some architecture, My front end application I have built using grunt,it running on localhost:3000 nodejs server, My BackEnd Application are in the Apache tomcat server (localhost:8080) . Basically backend application running on spring framework. guys i want to send request from my localhost:3000 to localhost:8080 using gruntjs.

Pls help me.

This is my grunt js file

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

    grunt.initConfig({
        concat: {
            options: {
                separator   : '\n\n//--------------------------------------------------\n\n;',
                banner      : '\n\n//---------------All Js file is here ---------------\n\n'
            },
            dist :{
                src :['components/scripts/*.js'],
                dest:'builds/development/js/scripts.js'
            }

        },
        sass : {
            dist :{
                options:{
                    style:'expanded'
                },
                files:[{
                    src:'components/sass/style.scss',
                    dest:'builds/development/css/style.css'
                }]
            }
        },
        connect:{
            server:{
                options:{
                    hostname:'localhost',
                    port:'3000',
                    base:'builds/development/',
                    livereload:true
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
              scripts: {
                files: ['builds/development/**/*.html',
                        'components/scripts/**/*.js',
                        'components/sass/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['concat','sass'],
                options: {
                  spawn: false,
                  livereload:true
                },
              },
            }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

    grunt.registerTask('default',['concat','sass','connect','watch']);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you have to write separate node server and register with grunt task.

```
var http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var server = http.createServer(function(){
    httpProxy.createProxyServer({target: 'http://localhost:8080'}).web(req, res);
});

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('server', function() {
        // this.async(); // run forever
        server.listen(8000);// Front End Server Listening Port
    });
};
```